# SQL Alter Table WITH Value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am faced with a vexing issue. I created a table using the function:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Aircraft (Type, EngineType, Speed)
      VALUES ('$type', '$engine', '$mph')";
```

But I now want to add a column, so I use the function:

```
$sql = ("ALTER TABLE Aircraft ".
       "ADD COLUMN SubsonicORSupersonic VARCHAR(20) ".
       "AFTER Speed;")
```

But how do I attach the `VALUES` command to the above sql function? You can attach `VALUES` to `INSERT INTO`, but it seems you cannot attach `VALUES` to `ALTER TABLE`. How can I get around this?

Comment: You'd `UPDATE` it after adding the field.  You can assign a default value to to a field, but that doesn't seem like what you're after here.

Comment: Your query is not secure against sql injection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = ("UPDATE Aircraft ".
             "SET SubsonicORSupersonic = $data; ")
```